# It's skinny for the smartest chaps, a combination lock perhaps

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I am stuck on this riddle and cannot seem to find a link between the two phrases

> 'It's skinny for the smartest chaps,
>   A combination lock perhaps'

What is it?

Comment: Is there any other information you could provide for this? As it stands this riddle seems to be too vague to come to a definitive solution.

Comment: Also, where does it come from?

Comment: From a quiz I am doing and this all I have

Comment: If this is from an ongoing competition, it is not encouraged (or at least, add your sources).

Answer (score 3):

This might possibly be

> Master?

It's skinny for the smartest chaps

> Someone who is a "master" at something is towards the top of their field.

A combination lock perhaps

> Masterlock is a company that makes (as far as I know) primarily padlocks and combination locks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go with a super out of the box answer;

'It's skinny for the smartest chaps,
A combination lock perhaps'

> Life
>
> Life will easily seem short, almost ephemereal, 'skinny', for most thinkers or 'smart' people. Equally like a combination lock, it needs the exact precise circumstances in order to occur. (Right amounts of gravity, elements, etc... etc...)
>
> This line of thinking however also makes any answer that fits the themes of scarcity and complexity, work.